# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect :

Tags: python, windows, error-handling

Hi I need find solution to rename mp4 file:

```
    list_of_choice = ("satisfying","satisfying video","the most satisfying","most oddly satisfying","satisfying videos","the most satisfying video in the world","oddly satisfying videos","sand and slime","ASMR vertical","best oddly satisfying","best oddly satisfying video","satisfying video for sleep","oddly satisfying video to help you sleep","stress relief","satisfaction","no music satisfying","slime","satisfying video to make you sleep","original resource","funny videos") 
    word = random.choice(list_of_choice) 
    list_of_choice = ("satisfying","satisfying video","the most satisfying","most oddly satisfying","satisfying videos","the most satisfying video in the world","oddly satisfying videos","sand and slime","ASMR vertical","best oddly satisfying","best oddly satisfying video","satisfying video for sleep","oddly satisfying video to help you sleep","stress relief","satisfaction","no music satisfying","slime","satisfying video to make you sleep","original resource","funny videos") 
    word1 = random.choice(list_of_choice) 

    filename = word +"~"+ word1 + "~" + "#Shorts"
    file = "output" + f"{number:03}" + ".mp4"
    os.rename(file, filename +".mp4" )
```

The name of the file should be a filename and a old name of the file is file I do this because I can put it into the loop

error:

```
OSError: Windows can not read a string
```

Comment: please write the expected filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not allow you to use the pipe character `"|"` in a file name or path.

Maybe try:

```
filename = word +"~"+ word1 + "~" + "#Shorts"
```